# Running ffmpeg command in Android gives Protocol not found error for image path

Tags: android, command-line, ffmpeg

I am trying to use ffmpeg from Android command line to convert images into video. I have stored my sequence of images on sdcard. When I run ffmpeg command to convert images into video, ffmpeg command give me error `Protocol not found`.

My command is like this:

```
/data/data/package/files/ffmpeg -r 40 -qscale 2 -i /mnt/sdcard/images/img%d.jpg /mnt/sdcard/images/finalvideo.mp4
```

Error is like this `/mnt/sdcard/vid.mp4: Protocol not found`

I found the same error message mentioned in `error.c` file. But I am not getting the type of error and condition when it throws the error. Also when I run ffmpeg command i.e. `ffmpeg -protocols` from Android and Linux, the number of supported protocols are not same.

I found file and many protocols missing in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look this link: https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264
I am not sure that you are using an NDK FFMPEG